# Как можно добавить стиль css в сервлет?

Tags: html, css, java-ee, servlet

Мне нужно красиво оформить таблицу в двух вариантах: На jsp и в сервлете. На JSP все получилось, вот стиль.

```
    <style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 14px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            text-align: center;
        }

        td{
            background: greenyellow;
            color: green;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
            border-color: green;
        }


    </style>
```

Теперь мне нужно его же установить сервлету, но через

```
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 out.println("<html><style>...")
```

выводится обычный текст.

Как можно добавить стиль к сервлету?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стили вроде в head помещаются

```
  "<html><head><style>..."
```